# Duplicate messages while subscribe using MQTT JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I'm currently trying thingspeak and they provide developers to subscribe the data using MQTT protocol.

But when I try to implement, the data won't stop to subscribe even I don't publish any message.

```
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key: 2
```

And my javascript code is:

```
let client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://mqtt.thingspeak.com', {
    username: process.env.MQTT_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.MQTT_PASSWORD,
    clientId: 'TSC-' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8) + '-' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
    protocolId: 'MQTT',
    keepalive: 1,
    reconnectPeriod: 100 * 1
  })
client.subscribe('channels/channel/subscribe/fields/field1/key', { qos: 0 })
client.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
  console.log(`${topic}: ${payload}`)
})
```

Am I missing something? Or it's the host fault? Thank you.

Comment: We would need to know a LOT more about the whole system before anybody can help. The subscribing code looks ok, but it will be down to the broker and the publishing client as to how many messages it will receive.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be reconnecting multiple times and subscribing each time a connect happens. The ThingSpeak broker returns the last value when you first subscribe.

Comment: I don't think so because when I use RabbitMQ, it works perfectly.

Comment: Could you modify your code to also let the clientid? That way, if you are connecting multiple times, you will see that I the log.

Comment: Also, do you see the same behavior of duplicate messages with another client -- say something like mqtt.fx?

Comment: Nope, using mqtt.fx or mqtt box doesn't show same behavior.

Comment: Then it is likely that your code has some unexplained mode of connecting and subscribing to topics. Try writing to ThingSpeak developers and asking if they can provide you more information to debug your app.